# Prove a sequence of maps is a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm having problem to prove that, given a probability space $\left(\Omega, E, P\right)$ and $\left(X_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ a sequence of r.v. on $\Omega$ uniformly distributed in [0,1] , $\left(Y_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ is a sequence of r.v. on $\Omega$ where

$$Y_n(\omega)=\frac{1}{n}1_{\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right)}\left(X_n\left(\omega\right)\right)+1_{\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]}\left(X_n\left(\omega\right)\right)$$

I know that I should prove that $Y_n$ is a r.v. for any n and thus prove that inverse image of $Y_n$ on any Borel set belongs to the sigma-algebra of the same probability space of $X_n$.
First, should I consider only intervals in $[0,1]$ as Borel set?
Second, how does the proving go on?

Comment: You only need to check $Y_n^{-1}([0,c])\in E$ for each $n$.

Comment: Direct approach: $Y_n=g_n(X_n)$ for some measurable $g_n$, end of the proof.

Comment: Thank you, it was easier than I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$Y_n = g_n(X_n), $$
with $g_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $$g_n(x) = \frac1n\mathsf 1_{\left[0,\frac1n\right)}(x) + \mathsf 1_{\left[\frac1n,1\right]}(x).$$ It follows immediately that each $Y_n$ is measurable as the composition of measurable functions.

As for the distribution of $Y_n$, recall that the probability measure on $[0,1]$ induced by the uniform distribution is Lebesgue measure. It follows that $Y_n$ is discrete with
$$\mathbb P\left(Y_n=\frac1n\right) = \frac1n = 1-\mathbb P(Y_n=1). $$

Comment: Sorry but $X_n^{-1}\left(\left[0,\frac1n\right)\right)$ is a subset of $\Omega$ so what does $X_n^{-1}\left(\left[0,\frac1n\right)\right)(\omega)$ even mean?

Comment: @Did Indeed, that notation was not correct (or meaningful).